# is this expression "a polygon (concave) edge on a group of points" clear and idiomatic?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56664353/10253483) is discussing a programming problem.

the task is to draw some lines on the edge of 3 groups of data points.

[image]

rather than covering whole area.

[image]

is this expression "a polygon (concave) edge on a group of points" clear and idiomatic?

Answer (score 0):

No, I wouldn't say it's clear. I didn't understand what it meant until I looked at the picture on Stackoverflow and saw that the edge of the polygon that was being pointed to by the arrow was bent inward, which is what 'concave' means.

Interestingly, they didn't need any additional words to make it clear. I would have used 'using' instead of 'with'.

> How to draw a concave polygon edge on a group of points using Python?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, "... was bent inward" seems to be easier to understand. as for the choice of "with Python" or "using Python", I made this new post https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/215650/95456

Comment: That makes sense within the developer community. That's how we talk about coding languages in our work. But I think outside that community 'using' would be better. I'm think of how people who don't know what Python is would understand it.

Answer (score 0):

*Supplementary answer (I agree about "using Python"):*

Clearer than "*on* a group of points" would be

> How to draw a concave polygon **surrounding** a **given** group of points

"Given" is helpful because it helps the programmer understand that the points are part of the input.

Note, "concave" is a mathematical term and although the average layman might not understand it, and *some* programmers might not either, I think it is fair to use this term with programmers in a title.  Then in the fine print one could explain the meaning.